# Is there any guideline for having no space between rules?

Tags: html, css

Is there any guideline for having no space between rules? Is it ok to have no space like the following:

```
#Ellipse_1 {
    fill: rgba(0,157,255,1);
    cursor: context-menu;
}.Ellipse_1 {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

In my test it seems to work in Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Comment: Don't confuse selectors with rulesets

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

Comment: Nothing limits you from writing that way, CSS minifiers are working that way and removing all returns and spaces - it works fine, but what is your purpose to do it manually? It's harder to read

Comment: seems it works for browsers but human being.

Comment: @VladislavAkhmetvaliyev it started as an accident but only related rulesets are grouped. i can change it to add a line break.

Comment: @Quentin correct. still waking up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CSS grammar is described [in the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#q4.0):

> ```
> stylesheet  : [ CDO | CDC | S | statement ]*;
> statement   : ruleset | at-rule;
> at-rule     : ATKEYWORD S* any* [ block | ';' S* ];
> block       : '{' S* [ any | block | ATKEYWORD S* | ';' S* ]* '}' S*;
> ruleset     : selector? '{' S* declaration? [ ';' S* declaration? ]* '}' S*;
> selector    : any+;
> declaration : property S* ':' S* value;
> property    : IDENT;
> value       : [ any | block | ATKEYWORD S* ]+;
> any         : [ IDENT | NUMBER | PERCENTAGE | DIMENSION | STRING
>               | DELIM | URI | HASH | UNICODE-RANGE | INCLUDES
>               | DASHMATCH | ':' | FUNCTION S* [any|unused]* ')'
>               | '(' S* [any|unused]* ')' | '[' S* [any|unused]* ']'
>               ] S*;
> unused      : block | ATKEYWORD S* | ';' S* | CDO S* | CDC S*;
> ```

White space (`S`) is optional (`*`) after the `}` at the end of a ruleset. A ruleset is a type of statement. A stylesheet can consist of a series of statements.

There's no requirement for whitespace between them.

That said, whitespace aids readability so you should include it when writing CSS. (Minified CSS for production is another story).